# How to make this type of progress bar javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have done html and css ..

HTML CODE -

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="top">
    <center><li><a href="#one" class="button">GENERATE</a></li></center>
  </ul>
  <div class="box" id="one">
    <span style="width:1%"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE -

```
.box {
left: 50px;
right: 50px;
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 50px;
border: 2px solid #000;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
background-color: #f90;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
-ms-transition: all 1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear;
-0-transition: all 1s linear;
transition: all 1s linear;
}
.box: target {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
-ms-transition: all 1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 1s linear;
-0-transition: all 1s linear;
transition: all 1s linear;
}
#one {
height: 20px;
margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
position: relative;
background: #555;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
#one > span {
display: block;
height: 100%;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top,   
color- stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84)) );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(43,194,83)  
37%, rgb(84,240,84) 69% );
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0   
-2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -2px   
6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px    
rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#one > span:after, .animate > span > span {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-
stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color- 
stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color- 
stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent),   
to(transparent) );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,   
rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent );
z-index: 1;
-webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
-moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
background-size: 50px 50px;
-webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.animate > span:after {
display: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
0% {
background-position: 0 0;
}
 100% {
background-position: 50px 50px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
0% {
background-position: 0 0;
}
100% {
background-position: 50px 50px;
}
}
.orange > span {
background-color: #f1a165;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-   
stop(0, #f1a165),color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a);
}
.red > span {
background-color: #f0a3a3;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color- 
stop(0, #f0a3a3),color-stop(1, #f42323));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
}
.nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
-webkit-animation: none;
-moz-animation: none;
background-image: none;
}
a.button {
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: initial;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Now what i want is that when someone clicks on the button, the progress bar start loading and stop at 50% and open popup window.

In that popup window i want to show some text with button.

DEMO - [MYCODE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nyq8u/605/)

Comment: You are probably newbie in JavaScript not in Java - this isnt the same

Comment: hm..yes but please give some solution..

Comment: i dont know what do You mean by In that popup window i want to show some text with button.

Comment: So what's not working? What are you having issues with? The question is not clear for me right now.

Comment: ok let me explain...i want when someone clicks on the submit button progress bar starts loading and stops at 50% ...and show a popup window..

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good example of progress bar for beginners:
[example of progress bar](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp)

There is a full code for your question

```html
<html>
<style>
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">0%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 50) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use the `<progress>` element?